# How to sort a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, lambda

I want to sort a nested dictionary by value and remainder by another value and again, remainder by another value. I have three criteria. To the two of three of them I want to assign reverse=True, but for the third criteria I want to assign reverse=False. How to do it using reversed and lambda?
Here is a piece of code:

```
result = sorted(dict_punkty.items(), key=lambda k: (k[1]["W"], k[1]["PKT"], k[1]), reverse=True)
```

k[1]["W"] and k[1]["PKT"] must be in reverse and k[1] not in reverse order.

Comment: If the values are numeric, you can just sort by `- value` for the ones you want in reversed order. But we don't know, so you should provide a minimal sample dict.

Comment: {'Jan': {'W': 1, 'PKT': 25}, 'Artur': {'W': 1, 'PKT': 20}, 'Karol': {'W': 0, 'PKT': 10}}

Comment: @kasiabadio: `k[1]` is a dict, but order comparison is [not allowed](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) on dicts in Python 3, and even in Python 2, the ordering of dicts is [consistent but not defined](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons). So (I'm assuming you're using Python 2) what does it even mean for `k[1]` to be sorted "not in reverse order"? How is that different than reverse order, since the order is not defined? Do you mean `k[0]` as the third item instead?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find something shorter, so I suggest the following solution:

```
dict_punkty={'Jan': {'W': 1, 'PKT': 25}, 'Artur': {'W': 1, 'PKT': 20}, 'Karol': {'W': 0, 'PKT': 10}}

# Put key names in a list sorted in reverse order
names = sorted(dict_punkty.keys(), reverse=True)

# Put names and their order in a temporary dictionary
names = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(names)}

# Put the data in a list of tuples replacing key names with order numbers
result = [(names[k[0]], k[1]) for k in dict_punkty.items()]

# Sort the list of tuples
result = sorted(result, key=lambda k: (k[1]["W"], k[1]["PKT"], k[0]), reverse=True)

# Reverse names/orders as keys/values in the temporary dictionary
names = {i: name  for name, i in names.items()}

# Get the final result by replacing the order numbers with key names
result = [(names[k[0]], k[1]) for k in result]

print(result)
```